# WKUserScript not call in iOS10, but works in iOS9

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview, wkuserscript

I'm having code which perfectly works in iOS 9, but not working in iOS 10, specifically doBar() not called. Here in WKWebView I'm injecting javascript code.

```
let jsFoo = "function doFoo() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.doFoo.postMessage(\"doFoo\"); }"
let jsBar = "class MyInterface { static doBar() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.doBar.postMessage(\"doBar\"); } }"

let fooScript = WKUserScript(source: jsFoo, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
let barScript = WKUserScript(source: jsBar, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)

contentController.addUserScript(logoutScript)
contentController.addUserScript(openPDFScript)

contentController.add(self, name: "doFoo")
contentController.add(self, name: "doBar")
```

In web page js code make calls:

```
window.doFoo() // works in both iOS 9 and iOS 10
window.MyInterface.doBar() // works in iOS 9, but NOT working in iOS 10
```

Safari debugger shows that in iOS 10 window.MyInterface is undefined, however user-script with doBar code is present.

How can I inject doBar properly, so it will work in iOS 10, assuming that web code I can't change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as I'm not JS developer I thought that injected code was fine. But it's not for iOS 10 jsBar have to be:

```
let jsBar = "function MyInterface() {}; { MyInterface.doBar = function() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.doBar.postMessage(\"doBar\"); };"
```